# Hiding and unhiding a column changes the automatic width of a column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I found the following code to create a link to hide/unhide a specific column

```
// JS
$('a.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    search = ":contains(" + $(this).text() + ")"
    var column = table.column(search);
    column.visible( ! column.visible() );
});

// HTML
Hide/unhide column: <a class="toggle-vis">Cost</a>
```

However when I hide and unhide a column, the column width is all messed up (column width changes to be equal to the header width and looks really scrunched up).

Is there a way to tell DataTables to redo the column width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to use [columns.adjust()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust())

Throwing `table.columns.adjust().draw();` after `column.visible( ! column.visible() );` fixed the problem